# Spring Repository query by multi-valued property

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, single-page-application, spring-data-jdbc

Trying to solve a problem where I have a class Student.

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    UUID id;
    String name;
    Long year;
    List<Attribute> attributes;
}
```

And a class Attribute

```
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String field;
    private String value;
}
```

Now I wanna search by year and by a list of attributes.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, UUID> {
    Page<Student> findStudentByYearAndAttributesIn(Long year, List<Attribute> attributes, Pageable pageable);
}
```

A possible search would be to look for all the students from the year 2000 who had brown or blond hair or brown or blue eyes.

```
{
  "hair" : ["brown","blonde"],
  "eyes" : ["brown","blue"]
}
```

When I try to run this project I get an error

```
Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.example.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Cannot query by multi-valued property: attributes; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot query by multi-valued property: attributes
```

How can I query for this **multi-valued properties**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to define a custom query in a `@Query` annotation.